# Jest can't use the HOC from js files but works correctly with HOC from tsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

When I import an HOC from tsx file, everything is ok. But when I change the extension to js, I see a Jest error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token. This usually means that you are trying to import a file that Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> ```
>   By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>   Here's what you can do:
>    • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>    • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>    • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
> ```

My jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  automock: false,
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/_internals/jest/setup.js',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(less|svg|png|css|pdf|woff|woff2)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    ...mappers,
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/lib/', '/dist/', '/.tmp/', '/git/'],
  testMatch: null,
  testRegex: '/tests/[a-zA-z-_]+\\.spec\\.(tsx|ts)$',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
};
```

My HOC:

```
export function myHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        actions();
      }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

export default myHOC;
```

My test:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Component } from '..';

jest.mock('myHOC', () => jest.fn());

describe('Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Component data={undefined} />);
  });
  it('should return null if there are no data', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBe(null);
  });
});
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "env" : {
    "test" : {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: Since you're using `ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel` it might be useful to share your babel configuration

Comment: @teneff, Added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/) documentation that the preset that you're currently using will let babel handle the `.js` files

> **ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel**: TypeScript files will be handled by ts-jest, and JavaScript files will be handled by babel-jest.

so you should either:

### add @babel/preset-react

this will transform all the jsx

**`.babelrc`**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
  "env" : {
    "test" : {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

or

### use ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts

and add if needed

**`tsconfig.json`**

```
{
 //...
 allowJs: true
}
```

**Edit:** if your application is working when myHOC is `.js` you should probably go with the second option